# Sublime is uploading files into root instead of sub directories

Tags: laravel, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sftp

Probably a simple solution, just never encountered the problem before.

I try to upload lets say welcome.blade.php which is located in

```
resources/views/welcome.blade.php
```

but sublime is just uploading to the root instead.

I'm using the SFTP package for this and have not encountered this issue before.

The stftp-config file remote path is correct..so I cant figure out what this could be.

Here is the sftp-config file

```js
{
    // The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
    // Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

    // sftp, ftp or ftps
    "type": "ftp",

    "save_before_upload": true,
    "upload_on_save": false,
    "sync_down_on_open": false,
    "sync_skip_deletes": false,
    "sync_same_age": true,
    "confirm_downloads": false,
    "confirm_sync": true,
    "confirm_overwrite_newer": false,

    "host": "their_host",
    "user": "their_user",
    "password": "",
    //"port": "22",

    "remote_path": "/domains/theirsitename.com/html/",
    "ignore_regexes": [
        "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
        "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
        "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
    ],
    //"file_permissions": "664",
    //"dir_permissions": "775",

    //"extra_list_connections": 0,

    "connect_timeout": 30,
    //"keepalive": 120,
    //"ftp_passive_mode": true,
    //"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
    //"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
    //"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

    //"preserve_modification_times": false,
    //"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
    //"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
    //"remote_locale": "C",
    "allow_config_upload": true,
}
```

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to solve the problem. Please [edit] it and post your config file, making sure to remove sensitive information like passwords and server names.